# How to Filter a vector layer in pyQGIS and rasterize it

Tags: pyqgis

I am building a QGIS plugin and I need to filter a vector layer (point of interest from OSM) in pyQGIS in this way: I need just the features that fall in a certain category (es: extract just alpine_hut from the 'fclass' field) so that I could rasterize just the filtered layer.
Now, I have tried different way but I am not be able to populate correctly a new vector layer with the filtered data:

attempt 1:

```
# expression1 = '"fclass" = \'alpine_hut\''
expression1 = "fclass = 'alpine_hut'"
request1 = QgsFeatureRequest().setFilterExpression(expression1) 
alpine_hut = poi_layer.getFeatures(request1)

# I can get the ids..
# ids = [s.id() for s in alpine_hut]
# print(ids)


# Iterate over the features - IT IS EMPTY..
for feature in alpine_hut:  
    print(feature.attributes())
    geometry = feature.geometry()
    print(geometry.asWkt())  

    
# try out other way to get geometries
g = list()  
for f in poi_layer.getFeatures():
    if f.id() in ids:
        g.append(f.geometry())
print(g)

        
# generate filtered layer
geometry_type = QgsWkbTypes.Polygon
fields = [QgsField("id", QVariant.Int), QgsField("name", QVariant.Double)]

# Create a new vector layer
# layer = QgsVectorLayer("{}?crs=epsg:4326".format(geometry_type), "AlpineHut", "memory")
layer = QgsVectorLayer("MultiPolygon?crs=epsg:4326",
                    "alpinehut", "memory")
layer.startEditing()
# Set the layer's fields
layer.dataProvider().addAttributes(fields)
layer.updateFields()


for _id, _geom in zip(ids, g):
    

    attributes = [_id, 'name']
    
    feature = QgsFeature()

    # Set the feature's attributes
    feature.setAttributes(attributes)
            
    # Set the feature's geometry
    feature.setGeometry(_geom)

    # Add the feature to the layer
    layer.dataProvider().addFeatures([feature])
    layer.updateExtents()  
    layer.updateFields()
    
layer.commitChanges()

        
print('adding layer')
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(alpine_hut)
```

In the code above the apine_hut object has the ids of the filtered points, but no geometry or other attributes seems to be stored. The when I try to save the shapefile it has no data, just field name I have provided.

attempt 2:

```
    # filter the dataset
    filter_string = "fclass = 'alpine_hut'"
    poi_layer.setSubsetString(filter_string)

    # try to rasterize the filtered dataset
    layer_result = helper.rasterize_numerical_feature(poi_layer, dem, column=None, burn=0.0)
    layer_raster_path = layer_result['OUTPUT']
    layer_raster = gdal.Open(layer_raster_path)
    layer_arr = layer_raster.GetRasterBand(1).ReadAsArray()
    print(np.unique(layer_arr, return_counts=True))
```

In the code above I have just tried to apply a filter and rasterize the output, but it returns an all-zeros array (the rasterize function works properly with the not filtered layer, and the input vector has the requested active filter in the QGIS interface as output).

attempt 3:

```
    fieldname = 'fclass' 
    
    for f in poi_layer.getFeatures():
        if f[fieldname]==r'alpine_hut':
            poi_layer.select(f.id())
    
    selected_features = poi_layer.selectedFeatures()

    # Create a new memory layer to store the selected features
    memory_layer = QgsVectorLayer("Polygon", "selected_points", "memory")
    
    # Add the selected features to the memory layer
    memory_layer.dataProvider().addFeatures(selected_features)        
    
    
    layer_result = helper.rasterize_numerical_feature(memory_layer, dem, column=None, burn=0.0)
    layer_raster_path = layer_result['OUTPUT']
    layer_raster = gdal.Open(layer_raster_path)
    layer_arr = layer_raster.GetRasterBand(1).ReadAsArray()
    print(np.unique(layer_arr, return_counts=True))
```

finally I tried to select the features and then rasterized them but again, the selection works well when I look at the layer loaded in QGIS but when rasterizing I get an all-zeros array.

Seems like I am missing something, do you have any suggestions?

EDIT:
seems like the attempt 3 works properly, I have found a problem in the rasterization actually! however I would like to make the 'attempt 1' works as well

Comment: maybe try this `features = poi_layer.getFeatures('"fclass" = \'alpine_hut\'')`

Comment: you can also create a temp layer like this `temp_layer = poi_layer.materialize(QgsFeatureRequest().setFilterExpression('"fclass" = \'alpine_hut\''))`

Comment: thanks actually it worked! however I can see the layer is stored just in the memory and I can visualize it making a buffer for example, it doesn't appear direclty in qgis interface

Comment: Use the following command `QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(temp_layer)`